# nrerror: root must be bracketed by zbrent

Tags: error-handling, input

What doe the error below mean?

```
nrerror:root must be bracketed by zbrent
STOP program terminated by nrerror
```

I get it when running a model with some inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I started googling the right things, it turns out that the line below is a way of handling errors where an expected input is missing that is often used in Fortran based code.

```
nrerror:root must be bracketed by zbrent
```

The second line (below) is a formulaic abort code in fortran which you can find in "Numerical Recipies in Fortran 90" W.H. Press (1996)

```
STOP: program terminated by nrerror
```

If you try to look up the two things together you won't get anywhere.

If anyone else encounters this error I recommend looking at a difference checker with a working and a non-working input file for a mistake in whatever input file you are using. (If I'd looked a bit closer then I would have seen that in a line I deliberately changed a 0.0d6, was missing.)

Hopefully others can learn from my mistakes.